# Can you suggest a motor that would be suitable for these parameters?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am trying to specify a motor, but I don't know where to start. I need it to be able to:

Lift a weight of $200kg$,
through a height of $2m$,
Using a lead-screw with the following dimensions:

$$OD = 26mm\\ Pitch = 5mm\\ Core =21mm\\ Mean\ Diameter=23.5mm$$

Comment: Please can you provide more details? How fast do you need to cover the 2m height? Do you need to accelerate at a certain rate? Why are you required to use that specific reason? What's the design intent that is driving your decisions?